# Extra space in awk output

Tags: awk

Why do I get the white space before and after the delimiter in the following example?

```
awk -F'^'  '{print $1,":",$2}' SERVER_2012-02-29-12-15-00
3969 : 1272
3969 : 1272
3969 : 1272
```

I expect the results as below without any space:

```
3969:1272
3969:1272
3969:1272
```

The text file looks like this...

```
cat SERVER_2012-02-29-12-15-00
3969^1272^14.140.90.242^^IN^como^2012-02-29
3969^1272^14.140.90.242^^IN^como^2012-02-29
3969^1272^14.140.90.242^^IN^como^2012-02-29
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
awk -F'^'  '{print $1":"$2}' SERVER_2012-02-29-12-15-00
3969:1272
3969:1272
3969:1272
```

To concatenate the fields with a `:` remove the `,`'s.

Or change the output field separator `OFS` to null.

```
awk -F'^' -vOFS='' '{print $1",:,"$2}' SERVER_2012-02-29-12-15-00
3969:1272
3969:1272
3969:1272
```

Comment: Or change the OFS to ":" and just `print $1, $2`

Answer (score 6):

Solutions have been given, but no complete explanation...

It is because when you use `print` with many parameters (separated by coma) it puts a *Field Separator* between the values.  From the `awk` man:

> print expr-list
>
> Print expressions.  Each expression is separated
>                         by  the  value  of  the OFS variable.  The output
>                         record is terminated with the value  of  the  ORS
>                         variable.

The string concatenation operator in `awk` is not coma, neither `+`, but *space*: `str = str1 str2` concatenate `str1` and `str2`.